# How can I set more than 1 date field in this rails create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

One field gets set but the other one doesn't.

My controller has the following new method:

```
  def new 
    @link = Link.new
    @link.content_date=Time.new().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    @link.url_address='http://'
    @link.verified_date = Time.new()
    @groups = Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_name, g.id] }
    @group_name =
      if params[:group_id]
        'for the '+Group.find(params[:group_id]).group_name + ' group.'
      else
        ''
      end 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end 
  end
```

and then a create method of

```
  def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    @link.content_date = Time.new().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if @link.content_date.nil?
    @link.verified_date = Time.new() if @link.verified_date.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Link was successfully created, '# + http_check_msg
        format.html { redirect_to(@link) }
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Error, Link was not created.'
        @groups = Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_name, g.id] }
        format.html { render :action => "new"}
      end
    end
  end
```

However only my `content_date` field is being set, not my `verified_date` field.

Why is that?

fyi, table has:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| url_address    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
| created_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content_date   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| verified_date  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and my link model has

```
attr_accessor :verified_date
```

Comment: Are you trying to create empty Time.new? Maybe you want to use Time.now instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your model:

```
attr_accessor :verified_date
```

Rails adds setters for database columns. When you declare a `attr_accessor` with the same name than an existing column, you override the setter Rails added and the assigned value will not be stored in the database.